# Margin between parent and child blocks

Tags: html, css

After so long I have noob question.

I do not understand why this problem happens

In Example 1, the expected result is correct, apply the margin between parent (gray) and child (red).

http://jsfiddle.net/48nTD/1/

HTML

```
<div class="parent odd">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent even">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.odd{
    background: #dddddd;
}

.even{
    background: #bbbbbb;
}

.block{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

In Example 2, the result is not as expected, not apply the margin between parent (dark-gray) and your child (green)

Apply the margin to child, but visually down the parent with block child.

http://jsfiddle.net/GUYjJ/

HTML

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="block left"></div>
    <div class="block right"></div>
</section>
<section class="row features">
    <div class="block"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.row{
    height: 540px;
}

.block{
    height: 320px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.left, .right{
    width: 40%;
}

.left{
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

.right{
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}

.features{
    background: #454545;
}

.features .block{
    background: green;
    width: 60%;
}
```

I do not understand the reason for this behavior.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to `.features`

```
.features{padding-top:1px;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GUYjJ/1/)

Comment: Although not a good practice but I'll take this is another solution as it initially did not plan to add padding to that block.

Thanks for replying.